# Is high earth to neutral voltage in single phase power supply system indication of high earth resistance?

Tags: grounding, neutral

In a single phase power supply system, if I measure the earth to neutral voltage, can I use it to indicate the health or status of the earth resistance i.e. if E-N voltage is high, is it due to earth resistance being high?

Is my following understanding correct:

1. In single phase electrical system,  if earth resistance is high, earth to neutral voltage will be high.
2. Corollary- High earth resistance is the ONLY reason for high earth to neutral voltage in single phase electrical system.

Comment: 1)Not necessarily. It might be high neutral resistance. Either way something is wrong and needs professional attention. 2) Not necessarily. Earth current may (and normally should) be low. High earth resistance may be undetected until another fault occurs. 3) See 1 and 2)

Comment: Which earthing system you mean? Isn't earth bonded to neutral at least at some point? So neutral to earth voltage should be quite low, unless that bond is broken at some point or huge currents flow either on neutral or earth.

Comment: @Justme earth bonded to neutral at generators / transformers plus at every house / load in low-voltage systems.

Comment: @schnedan you got to pick a mains earthing system like TT or TN-C-S or whatever based on regulations where you live and go by it. So the earthing system depends on which places it is allowed and forbidden to bond neutral and earth.

Comment: really? as a electrical engineer that's totally new to me.

Comment: @schnedan It depends in what kind of EE you are and what you have specialized in. If you have a Master's EE degree in electronics or embedded systems, most likely you have not heard much about what power engineering courses contain. The subject of grounding may have been a small area of some basic course, and it may not have contained in-depth differences of different earthing systems.

Comment: @Justme it was sarcasm.

Comment: @schnedan I wasn't sure so I assumed you were serious.

Answer (score 2):

first check the earthing system in use..  if you have  TN-S , TN-C or TN-C-S then you have a bad earth  connection.  On the other hand if you have an IT mains which happens when you have 2 phases in stead of phase and neutral... in the last case its normaal to measure high Earth - Neutral( or maybe other phase ..  hope this helps